# Java: multiple ++-increases in one line. Which one first?

Tags: java, virtual-machine

Hey,
I have the following two lines of code:

```
result[i] = temp[i] + temp[i + 1] + " " + temp[i + 2];
i += 2;
```

I am wondering if this line of code would do the same:

```
    result[i] = temp[i] + temp[i++] + " " + temp[i++];
```

Can I be sure, that **EVERY** VM would process the line from the left to the right?
Thanks,
Tobi

Comment: Probably not. Depends whether it's in the spec.

Comment: The two lines are very very different:  One changes i, and the other does not, and I'd be afraid of side-effects elsewhere in your code from the second line.

Comment: result[i] = temp[i] + temp[++i] + " " + temp[++i]; will work.

Comment: Your two codes are obviously not the same. i++ is the post increment operator. So i++ will first return the old i and then increment.

Comment: The language spec is very precise. VMs do not differ in things this basic.

Comment: Given that Java generally avoids the trouble of UB, I suppose it *is* in the spec. However, (1) you want preincrement to make it equivalent and (2) it's not the most obvious code anyway (you have to ask here, and nearly everyone else will have to look it up as well!).

Comment: @Hovercraft the first code snippet contains two lines, look at the second one ;)

Comment: @Dunaril: sorry -- did not see!  Thanks!

Comment: Even if it was the same, the first code sample is much much more easier to understand, maintain and debug. This is much more important than saving a line of code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.
>
> It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification. Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right evaluation of expressions.

Comment: fix the link. It's pointing at the wrong place. Also you found the place I was looking for.

Comment: +1 For "using the specification". Perhaps emphasis on some bits? :)

Answer (score 7):

It should be

```
result[i] = temp[i] + temp[++i] + " " + temp[++i];
```

if I am not wrong, so that the indexes are computed after each incrementation.
Apart from that it should work.

Comment: Good, you were the first to recognized they most definitely NOT the same.

Answer (score 7):

Let's just try actually quoting [the source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

> Operators on the same line have equal
>   precedence. When operators of equal
>   precedence appear in the same
>   expression, a rule must govern which
>   is evaluated first. **All binary
>   operators except for the assignment
>   operators are evaluated from left to
>   right**; assignment operators are
>   evaluated right to left.

It looks like someone [found a link to the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978900/java-multiple-increases-in-one-line-which-one-first/4978933#4978933) as well.

Comment: +1 for also quoting a repitable source. Is there a reference in the spec somewhere rather then on a tutorial? I couldn't find one. Are we the only ones who interpreted the question correctly?

Comment: I am heading out so I don't have time to check but if I find it, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: the other poster found the reference to the spec.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not the same. When you put the ++ after i it implies that it is postfix, i.e. i will first be used and THEN incremented.

So:

```
result[i] = temp[i] + temp[i++] + " " + temp[i++];
```

would be the same as the below if i = 1:

```
result[1] = temp[1] + temp[1] + " " + temp[2];
```

and after this statement i would be sitting with value of 3.

For it to be the same as:

```
result[i] = temp[i] + temp[i + 1] + " " + temp[i + 2];
```

You should use the prefix increment operator, i.e:

```
result[i] = temp[i] + temp[++i] + " " + temp[++i];
```

Comment: `++` also has side-effects -- another important distinction

Answer (score 2):

```
i++ will output the value and increment
++i will increment the value and output.
```