# Consider this code: "int s = 20; int t = s++ + --s;". What are the values of s and t?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, increment, decrement

cut to the chase, the answer is "s is 20, and t cannot be determined."
I understand the part that s is 20, but why t cannot be determined?
Please help me!

Comment: Where did you find the answer you're giving?

Comment: `t` can be determined: http://ideone.com/6ja0Kv

Comment: Did you think to, oh I don't know, try it and see? "t cannot be determined" is ... nonsense.

Comment: Code like this is never useful in real life... why are you interested?

Comment: I think by "can be determined", he does not mean that it'll run, but that it's the same in all runtimes and all compilers.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Then he'd ... still be wrong.

Comment: @BrianRoach I'm fairly sure you're quite right that it _is_ 100% determined behavior in Java (in C/C++ for example, it's explicitly undefined behavior), but I'd not bet my house on it without looking at the spec.

Comment: The Q is tagged Java. If it were tagged C (or anything else where that wasn't the case) then I wouldn't have posted that ;)

Comment: @BrianRoach I can bet my house now too :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/4978933/477878

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Heh, I was just digging through the JLS to find that so I could post a link to it. I should have figured it was already here somewhere.

Comment: Voting to reopen: While the expression is ugly and shouldn't be used in real code, I think this question isn't "too localized" because the answer is that it's well defined in Java (unlike C or C++) and follows very simple, natural rules of expression evaluation that Java *requires* be used. How can that be "too localized" if its a set of rules that every Java program must follow?  It's important for Java developers to understand this (especially those who come from the world of C).

Comment: For the record I voted "not a real question" because it was just an ugly question. If it were written as something coherent I wouldn't have. That being said, I should have closed it as a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629136/preincrement-postincrement-in-java (among others, I'm sure)

Comment: the answer is from myprogramminglab.com / our class in college use resources from that site. im not interested in code like that, either because it's very confusing. but i should submit my homework and that's one my homework problems :(

Comment: thank you for all of you! s is 20, and t is 40, I understand! i think the answer in that site was wrong

Answer (score 2):

```
int s = 20; 
int t = s++ + --s;
```

Working: increment(post increment) s to 21 (current value 20) + decrement(pre decrement) s to 20 (current value 20).

```
So, t=20+20;
And s =20;
```

After taking into account precedence and parentheses, Java guarantees that expressions will be evaluated left to right. For example, to evaluate eat() + drink() - beMerry(), Java will first evaluate eat(), then drink(), then perform the addition, then evaluate beMerry(), and finally perform the subtraction. eat() is evaluated before drink(), because eat() is to the left of drink(), and expressions are evaluated left to right. This guarantee is important because the invocations of eat() and drink() may have side effects that would differ if they were invoked in the opposite order.

Comment: You may want to explain a little _why_ you're calculating as you do (ie left to right, not right to left for example)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I edited my answer as you said. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators):

> Since the increment/decrement operator modifies its operand, use of
>   such an operand more than once within the same expression can produce
>   undefined results. For example, in expressions such as x − ++x, it is
>   not clear in what sequence the subtraction and increment operators
>   should be performed. Situations like this are made even worse when
>   optimizations are applied by the compiler, which could result in the
>   order of execution of the operations to be different than what the
>   programmer intended.

Now, you're answer should be pretty clear.
It sounds to me like the value of t may vary by compiler/optimizations.

Here is some more info:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Sequence-Points-Constrain-Expressions

Comment: This answer is valid for C/C++, but not for Java. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4978933/477878